# Calculation Space Inside Arbitrary Shape

Tags: matlab, mom

I want to solve the Laplace equation with an integral equation (MoM) within an arbitrarily-shaped (known function) closed curve boundaries. We found the value of a point given the coordinate in the interior solution space according to the boundary point. Does anyone know any algorithm or idea to implement this for all the points inside?

[image]

Comment: People FEM this things, rigth?

Comment: Not FEM, Boundary Element Method

Comment: FEM, BEM, FDM .... tehre are a lot of methods, and it depends what's yout objective, often you can use either. However this is a maths question, not a programming question, thus off-topic

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I especially mentioned it, method is "boundary element" or "moment method". My question is not about it's mathematic, it's about implementation. I need coordinates of points inside whole domain. just it

Comment: Then you need to explain it better! You just need a lot of coordinates? But there areinfinite points inside a domain! Please, try to be more speciic